# Find a consistent Linear system for g ,h and k?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am working on problem #25 of *Linear Algebra and its Applications* and the question asks:

> Find an equation involving $g$, $h$, and $k$ that makes this augmented matrix correspond to a consistent system:
>   $$\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
> 1& -4& 7& g \\
> 0& 3& -5& h \\
> -2& 5& -9& k
> \end{array}\right).$$
>   After I do $R_3 \gets 2R_1 + R_3$ and $R_3 \gets R_2 + R_3$
>   I end up with
>   $$\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c} 1& -4& 7& g \\ 0& 3& -5& h \\ 0& 0& 0& 2g+k+h
> \end{array}\right).$$

For this to be a consistent system the third row should be $\begin{pmatrix}0& 0& 0& 0\end{pmatrix}$,
so in order for this augmented matrix to be a consistent system then $2g + k + h =0$

The answer in the back of the book is $k - 2g + k = 0$.

Where am I going wrong with my calculation? Or is the book wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you wrote the book solution correctly? Also, from which book (author)? Also, I checked your solution using three different methods and it is correct. There is a typo/transcription problem somewhere.

Comment: I am using Linear Algebra and it's Applications 4th edition by Lay.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, the 3rd edition of Lay's  book has your answer to this question.

Comment: I just dug up a pdf of the 3rd edition solution manual and you are correct; I was correct and the 4th edition has the wrong answer.

Answer (score 1):

My answer 2g+k+h=0 is correct.